# Jquery Ajax working in Local Machine not in Server

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

HTML Code

```js
$('#btnTariefVerwijderen').click(function () {             
        if (TariefId != undefined && TariefId != "" && TariefId != null) {
            if (window.confirm("Weet u zeker dat u de gesselecteerde rij(en) wilt verwijderen uit de database?")) {
                var url = '/Onderhoud/DeleteTarief?TariefId=' + TariefId;
                $.ajax({
                    cache: false,
                    type: "GET",
                    url: url,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    //data: { objectId: objectId, type: type },
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (Data) {
                        TariefId = null;
                        DisplayVerordeningTariefGrid();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        else
            ShowMessage("Please select the tarief to delete");
    });
```

C# Code

```
       public ActionResult DeleteTarief(decimal TariefId)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _onderhoudRepository.DeleteTariefItem(TariefId,HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);
                //return RedirectToAction("SelecterenPuttenData", new { objectId = objectId, type = type });
                return Json(new { success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            else
            {
                return Json(new { success = false }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
```

The funtion is getting triggerd only in Local Machine but not in server. Can anyone help me out here.
Jquery files are working fine in Local Visual studio

Comment: what error do you get? Did u check ur network tab ?

Comment: @johnSmith In localhost [Visual Studio] i dont get any error but after deploying to server I get below error "GET http://webl.com/Controller/DeleteTarief?TariefId=18462&_=1628493439135 net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE" This in Console

Comment: Strange type decimal for TariefId? Are you sure that it is not typo? Can you give an example of  TariefId?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this ?

```
$('#btnTariefVerwijderen').click(function () {             
    if (TariefId != undefined && TariefId != "" && TariefId != null) {
        if (window.confirm("Weet u zeker dat u de gesselecteerde rij(en) wilt verwijderen uit de database?")) {
            $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                url: '@Url.Action("DeleteTarief", "Onderhoud")',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    "TariefId":TariefId,
                },
                success: function (Data) {
                    TariefId = null;
                    DisplayVerordeningTariefGrid();
                }
            });
        }
    }
    else
        ShowMessage("Please select the tarief to delete");
});
```

Comment: Works in Localhost not in server